# Sitecore and WFFM, cant specify rules for fields

Tags: sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

I have no option to set rules when selecting my fields within my form using WFFM and the Forms Designer.
Is there any requirements of things to be insatlled to get the rules option enabled?..(DBM, analytics, anything?), or is there any setting within Sitecore that needs to be enabled or something?

Comment: What have you installed in you Sitecore instance? Web, master, core, analytics?

Comment: What is your requirement, do you want to set rule on field bases of WFFM form?

Comment: "What is your requirement, do you want to set rule on field bases of WFFM form?"
yes, but as mentioned.. right now I don't even have the option to set rules..

Answer (score 0):

Can you check to see if you can add rules in Sitecore Web Forms for Marketers for that particular field?

Comment: thats what I would like to be able to do :), as of right now I cant add any rules for a particular field

Answer (score 0):

Please navigate on /sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Web Form for Marketers/Tags/Default path and here you will get a multilist field with name **Taxonomy** please select tags what rules you want to apply and after that all Rule will start showing in your Rule Set Editor.

Comment: There were already a few rules set there, and I just added all, but there is still no "Rules" options for specific/selected fields.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the Sitecore.Analytics.config file is disabled in your AppConfig\Include folder.

Comment: Rules can't be used without analytics? Can you elaborate on your answer?

Answer (score 0):

In the Sitecore.Xdb.config configuration file from the /App_Config/Include/ folder, there is an option for setting Tracking

```
<!--  XDB TRACKING ENABLED
      Determines whether tracking is enabled or not.
      Default value: true
-->
<setting name="Xdb.Tracking.Enabled" value="true" />
```

This needs to be true in order for the rule section to show up in the forms section.

Be aware that this option has license consequences according to https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/experience_management/configuring/configure_experience_management

Answer (score -2):

Please refer below link if you are using these specific rules.
https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/932002

Below is the solution in link:

> When creating forms using the Web Forms for Marketers module, it is
>   possible to configure different rules for the form fields. Such rules
>   can be used for hiding specific fields, setting field default values,
>   etc. However, the rules may not work when using the conditions from
>   the Item Information group, specifically the following ones:
>
> 1. where the item ID compares to value
> 2. where the item name compares to value
> 3. where the item template is specific template
>
> For example, the following rule will not hide the field when rendering
>   the form on the Home item: where the item name is equal to Home hide
>   element
>
> ***Solution***
>
> Apply the following patch to resolve the issue: Copy the
>   [Sitecore.Support.401148.dll](https://kb.sitecore.net/~/media/F1646529B69242EBA8E9BD2F9AC726F3.ashx?la=en) assembly into the /bin folder of your
>   solution. Change the Type field of the following items in the master
>   database as specified below:
>   /sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Definitions/Elements/Item
>   Information/Item ID:
>   Sitecore.Support.Rules.Conditions.ItemConditions.ItemIdCondition,Sitecore.Support.401148
>   /sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Definitions/Elements/Item
>   Information/Item Name:
>   Sitecore.Support.Rules.Conditions.ItemConditions.ItemNameCondition,Sitecore.Support.401148
>   /sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Definitions/Elements/Item
>   Information/Item Template:
>   Sitecore.Support.Rules.Conditions.ItemConditions.WhenTemplateIs,Sitecore.Support.401148
>   Publish the changes.

Comment: This may theoretically answer the question, but it would be best to include the essential parts of the answer here for future users, and provide the link for reference. [Link-dominated answers](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231) can become invalid through [link rot](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot).

Comment: Thanks! for your comments guys. Added link contents in the answer.